# Terraform outputs of "helm_release" resource

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

It is possible to export as an output a specific helm value that is not provisioned by Terraform?
For example, I created nginx ingress controller with Helm via terraform and I want to export the external IP of it. (The ip isn't created via terraform, this is an internal ip).

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @MarkoE In my outputs.tf file, I created a new output for that external IP.
Then, it looks like I have a couple of options (manifest,metadata etc.) but none of them relevant to export the IP value.

Comment: So the external IP was created outside of Terraform?

Comment: Yes and this is a private IP because this is an internal LB. (means that the specific IP is not even an Azure resource).

Comment: How was the internal LB deployed then?

Comment: @MarkoE Deployed with annotation to the helm chart:
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
    value = var.internal_lb (true or false depends on the end user choice)
  }

Comment: So Azure then has knowledge of that, meaning you can see that in the Azure console?

Comment: @MarkoE Correct.

Comment: You could use Azure CLI to fetch that value then, does that sound like a good idea? In combination with something like a `null_resource`.

Comment: Umm but I need it to be generic. Means that in order to fetch the value with Azure CLI will be complicated. I can fetch the value easily with Kubectl, you think it can be helpful?

Comment: Well, if that's what you need, go for it.

Comment: @MarkoE I'm not familiar with null_resource, it is possible to combine it with kubectl ?

Comment: Yup, you can use `local-exec` provisioner to run commands on the local file system. If you give me the command, I can try to fit it in an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you! 
This is the command: kubectl get svc kubernetes-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller -n kubernetes-ingress -o=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip}'

Comment: @MarkoE and how the Terraform output command should looks like?

Comment: Added additional explanation and resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `data` block in *terraform* to get outputs from existing resources, you can read more about that in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources).

in your case, you can do something like this:

```
data "kubernetes_service" "ingress_svc" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress_svc"
  }
}

output "instance_ip_addr" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.ingress_svc.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress[0].ip
}
```

you can read more about that in the Kubernetes provider [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service)

Comment: Could you please explain how you came up with the value? I mean the part about the "status", how it's an array indexed by 0, and has the rest "loadbalancer.0.ingress[0]
I douldn't find this in any of the documentation. I'm asking b/c I also want to extract the ingress class value,, so I can use it in other services. Thx.